# Model for predicting disease that is highly correlated with age

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, biostatistics, methodology

I am trying to train a model for predicting a disease that is correlated with age and gender. Extracted features seem to be both discriminatory for age, gender and the disease. What is a proper methodology in such case?
[image: age distribution]
It looks logical to create disease group with control group with distributions that are statistically similar in terms of age and gender, just to make model independent from these variables. However I see 2 problems here. First I am losing many samples in the process. Secondly, age and gender is discriminatory for the disease, which limits model effectiveness.

1. What is a proper way for developing production model for general population in such case?
2. How to show that model predicts more than just age and gender if trained on dataset that is not age and gender balanced? I can imagine that could be achieved by comparing with "dummy model" that always correctly predicts age and gender and uses disease prevalence to estimate the risk?

Comment: Not in expert in that - but seeing your control distribution falling sharply off at 50 sounds like a bad idea. Unless that is actually the target demographics that you are looking at. I don't know what sickness your are looking at - but just judging by the distribution of your disease and control group I would judge that basically anybody over the age of 50 or 55, has it. What you could do is to oversample the age groups (as in binned by 5 years or so) in control until they represent the actual demographics.

Comment: Isn't it a positive to be able to say under $50$ is minimal risk while over $50$ is a significant risk? That makes it seem like age is majorly predictive of disease.

Comment: We need more contextual information: sample size? How many /which predictors (apart from age and gender)? The histogram has three colors, what is the meaning? ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen You don't interpret the third color as the blue/orange overlap?

Comment: @Lutz do you suggest oversampling and undersampling both control and desease group to achieve distribution that is expected on production? or just control group?

Comment: @Dave That is true, age is a major factor - extracted features carry information about age but also beyond the age - after resampling both, control and disease group to have the same age and gender distribution the features are still predictive. My question is how approach a similar problem in general, when it comes to develop a model in production, should we resample these groups to make training independent from age and gender, or we should we not? I am looking for general guidelines or use cases

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen control group has 80 males and 100 females, disease group has 170 females and 240 males. ~17k feature vectors are derived from patient speech. (Many samples are for the same participant). Feature vector has length of few hundreds components. Histogram has only control and disease group, third color is the overlap

Comment: No, I do not see a reason to resample to make the outcome unrelated to the features. Your *hope* is that the features explain the outcome!

Comment: @Dave, Thank you for your comment. 
If I would not resample, is there a risk that features predict age and gender only? In other words model is not specific to the disease? .Is there any formal way to show that the model is predicting the disease in specific way, rather than estimating age and gender only?

Comment: I do not understand your concern. You don’t have to predict age and gender. You know those.

Comment: @Dave Sorry about that. I was not precise enough. My concern is to show that my model is specific to the disease. My goal is to develop a model that does not detect a different disease with similar age and gender distribution or detect it with lower probability, also the model would be superior to a model  based purely on age and gender. I am looking for approaches people use in practice in similar cases and if they resample dataset in some specific way to boost specificity and target these concerns.

Comment: What do you mean about another disease? Does your model know about other diseases?

Comment: @Dave Let me illustrate it on an examples. Many lifestyle diseases are correlated with age, e.x arteriosclerosis or diabetes type 2. My concern is that features would be "regressed" by model to age and gender therefore would predict these 2 different diseases with similar probabilities. How to make sure a model would be more specific to the first disease? I assume developing a dataset that has as many as possible of such diseases (classes, labels) would be helpful for model training that would predict them with higher specificity?

Comment: It sounds like you want to do a multi-label classification where a subject can be identified as both "diabetes" and "heart disease". Is that correct?

Comment: @Dave Most likely that is the case. I assume this would be much better approach than artificially adjust age and gender distribution? But what if we have labels for one disease only (binary classification). Would be there any approach in preparing  
training dataset (resampling, other techniques) to make a model more specific to the disease?

Comment: I assume you can't really resample your disease group sensibly to match the population. So I would go with just the control group. Also as you are concerned about it being specific to one disease I would try (I am not from the field - just a general thought I have about all these machinelearning tasks in health related fields) to include at least a reasonable amount (what ever that may exactly mean) of other disease cases. Just to make sure your not just figuring out that somebody is likely sick - but actually has just an inflammation in his knee.

Comment: A multilabel approach would get you to that somewhat - but would maybe tend to classify not seen diseases as one of the labels semi randomly. I would suspect having n models that classify for "has disease X" but where trained with X as training and Y, Z and healthy as control would outperform a X,Y,Z, healthy model on new data.